# Not able to fetch search result in Content search API with Solr and Azure

Tags: solr, content-search, indexing, azure-search

I am using content search API in Sitecore 9.1.1. However, it is not fetching result if i am using search with any of the template field. The below code fetching result based on template id but when we are trying to fetch result based on any template field then it is not showing any result.

Sharing Code:-

Template :-

```
Content 
ID         Single-Line Text
Name       Single-Line Text
Version    Number
```

Model :-

```
public class ModelSearchResult : SearchResultItem
    {
            [IndexField("id")]
            public string ID { get; set; }
            [IndexField("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [IndexField("version")]
            public int Version { get; set; }
    }
```

Code :

```
ISearchIndex index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index");

                using (IProviderSearchContext context = index.CreateSearchContext())
                {

                    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<ModelSearchResult>();
                    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.TemplateId == ID.Parse("{----}"));
                    var keywordPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<ModelSearchResult>();
                    keywordPredicate = keywordPredicate.Or(x => x.ID == ID.Parse(item.ID));
                    keywordPredicate = keywordPredicate.Or(x => x.Version == item.Version.Number);
                    predicate = predicate.And(keywordPredicate);
                    var queryable = context.GetQueryable<ModelSearchResult>();
                    queryable = queryable.Where(predicate);
                    var result = queryable.GetResults();
                }
```

Comment: Hi Sonu, looks like in 2nd predicate you are using different class -
var keywordPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<DataSourceSearchResult>();
so the name and version field that you are using, those are OOTB in searchResultItem class

Comment: I have updated the code. I am using the same class.

Comment: Can you please check with some other field name as well, because above fields seem OOTB as well, take another field like title and check with that

Comment: I have check with all the fields but it is not working. Is there any setting for the field index?

Comment: can you see solr dashboard and try to run your search query there and see if you are getting result there?

Comment: How to run query there i am not finding any way there for running query. Could you assist me ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110555/discussion-between-gaurav-agarwal-and-sonu).

Comment: @Sonu Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @Sreekrishnan, No